# How to transfer ether to Coinbase

Tags: ether

I downloaded the Ethereum Wallet from https://www.ethereum.org. I created a wallet. I have been mining to the wallet address from the app.

How do I transfer to Coinbase to sell it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to have an account on coinbase. On coinbase you can get a public key that is tied to your account. You send ether to that public key. I would do a test transaction to make sure it goes through, then a second one with the full amount of ether.

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking for the steps in "You send ether to that public key." Where do I initiate that part from? geth or something?

Comment: Ah, Ethereum Wallet has a simple Send button. I'm so dumb.